# Normalization Function for non-linear data

Tags: regression

I have gone through the linear normalization however its not solving my transformation. I need to convert the min and max in order of [0-1]

requirement:
Min Value = 0.0
Max Value = 15.0

However, for 0.1 it should give me a high value than liner transformation, something like 0.05.
The graph will be something like y=log(x) or y=root(x) for which 
at x =15, y =1.

Comment: The problem isn't really clear to me. What do you mean by linear normalisation? If you want a non-linear transformation to [0, 1] then perhaps a logistic transform would be suitable? It may help to expand on the properties you want the transformation to have.

Answer (score 0):

You may get what you want with the empirical CDF.

Let $X\sim F_X(x)$ be a (continuous) random variable. It is then the case that $F_X(X)\sim U(0,1)$. This is called the probability integral transform

In the discrete case, such as with data (an empirical distribution is discrete), the resulting distribution isn't quite uniform (and you can make it seriously nonuniform with many observations tied at the same value), but we still end up with the compression to $[0,1]$.

When we apply the empirical distribution to do the probability integral transform, we say that we are using the empirical CDF.

In R, if your data are saved in `x`, the transformed data are formed by `ecdf(x)(x)`.

I see two advantages to using the empirical CDF as the transformation:

1) It will always give transformed values in $[0,1]$.

2) It feels natural to me to use the data as a guide.